# Configure additional truststore in Spring Boot Tomcat Server

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, mtls

I have a spring boot client application and a server application. I am implementing MTLS client authentication part. I have a client certificate that is self signed and this needs to be added to a custom truststore in the server. Basically I am looking for a mechanism to add my custom truststore at runtime.

I want the default truststore and the custom truststore to be picked up. I implemented this using TomcatServletWebServerFactory but I did not have any luck. Can someone please help. I am looking for a programmatic solution.

I do not want to change the default java truststore. I still need that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not want to replace the existing truststore with your custom one (that could be done by running the JVM with a few system properties) you need to add code that trusts a peer if the builtin or a custom trusttore approve the client.

For this you need to create and install your own Trustmanager. See an example here: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/1535342/java-ssl-trustmanager

If the `checkClientTrusted` and `checkServerTrusted` methods do not raise an exception the certificate is approved. Leaving the methods empty would even turn off any certificate validation - not to be recommended.

Answer (score 0):

In order to establish a SSL connection with client certificates between a Spring client application and a Spring server application, there are a few things to note:

## Involved Trust Stores

There are two very different trust stores relevant in this context:

1. The trust store used by the client to determine whether it can trust the server's SSL certificate. When using the java.net package for client requests, the trust store is configured via the JVM property "javax.net.ssl.trustStore" - see e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/adminguide/cadminsslclient.html
2. The trust store used by Tomcat (the underlying servlet container used by Spring Boot in its default configuration) to determine whether it shall trust a client. This is configured via the spring application property "server.ssl.trust-store" - see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.server.server.ssl.trust-store

In the context of a Spring server application the first one is relevant for connections which the server makes to a second server - so only when the server acts as client as well - e.g. when acting as a proxy server.

The second trust store is relevant for connections between the server and its clients. This is the one you need to deal with.

## Certificates in the Tomcat Trust Store

The trust store which is used by Tomcat does NOT contain the client certificates. Instead, it must contain the certificate of the Certificate Authority who has signed the client certificate. So when using self-signed certificates, you need to install the CA certificate which you have generated on your own.

The big advantage of this is, that you do not need to change the server trust store, when you grant access to new clients.

The downside is, that you have to handle a certificate revocation. The CRL (certificate revocation list) is also stored in the trust store. See:

[CRL Explained: What Is a Certificate Revocation List?](https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/crl-explained-what-is-a-certificate-revocation-list/)

## Merging the Default Trust Store and the Custom Trust Store

As now should be clear, this is not a good idea and would constitute a major security flaw, as it would allow any client which has a certificate signed by a CA in the default trust store (which can be easily obtained) to connect to the server. The server trust store must only contain those certificates which you use to sign your client certificates!

And there is no need to merge the two, as this are totally separate trust stores with totally different functions.

But, of course it is technically feasible to merge trust stores. This can all be done by keytool - see below.

## Managing Trust Stores

Adding, deleting, exporting, listing, and printing certificates and CRLs can all be done via the Oracle command line tool "keytool", which is part of the OpenJDK. See

[keytool Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/tools/keytool.htm#JSWOR-GUID-5990A2E4-78E3-47B7-AE75-6D1826259549)

Comment: Hi @Udo , Thanking for your answer. I am actually looking for a solution through java programatically. I want to merge my custom CA"s and the default CA's without tampering the default truststore.

Comment: Hi @SJB, this can be achieved by creating a copy of the JRE default key store and importing the custom certificates. The key tool is fully written in Java [Keytool Source Code](https://github.com/eagle518/jdk-source-code/blob/master/jdk6u21_src/j2se/src/share/classes/sun/security/tools/KeyTool.java) and there is also a Java API to call it directly from Java and not via the command line: [Keytool API](https://www.mojohaus.org/keytool/keytool-api/) and a maven plugin to invoke keytool. It's the standard JDK tool to manipulate key/trust stores...

Comment: Hi @Udo, no that is not what I am looking for. I am looking to add my truststore at runtime. The system truststore should also be picked up. Can this be achieved by TomcatServletWebServerFactory?

Comment: Hmm, very strange requirement and definitely no out-of-the-box Spring  functionality. Perhaps, you can describe more precisely what you really want to achieve and why (give a little bit more background).

Comment: I have a client certificate that is self signed. This is added to my custom truststore file client-truststore.jks. This is not present in server. I do not want to change the default java truststore of my server. I want that as well as this truststore to be read by the server. So when the client communicates with the certificate, server can get the CA

Comment: Sorry, but this is very confusing to me: Do you want to import the custom client cert to a custom server trust store? Why? As stated in my answer, you need to import the CA cert. Why do you want to integrate it with the „default java trust store“? As stated in my answer, the JRE trust store is only used for java.net Client connections done in the server app. It has nothing to do with client certificates. There is NO default trust store for server SSL connections with client certificates.

Comment: Or are you trying to make client connections within the server with the certificate which was uploaded by a client? This is a totally different story and much easier, as the java.net trust store can be changed on the fly without the need to restart the sever. You just need to change the JVM property for this, e.g. to a temporary key store which only holds the custom certificate.

Comment: You need to be more precise, which connection are you trying to establish: What is the client? what is the server? What is the purpose of the custom certificate: key store on the client side? or trust store on the server side? How does the certificate gets to the location where you want to use it: Is it uploaded? when yes, from where to where? This is all totally unclear to me from your description.

Comment: Hi @Udo, My client is self signed. It is for my local testing. It is created as a CA. I want the server to trust this CA. So when I manually add this CA to the default java truststore, my connection works fine. I am looking for a programmatic solution. I have the client cert added to a trusstore and this truststore has to be present in the server. I know I can set java.ssl property or server.ssl property for this. But when I do that, this becomes the only truststore that the server will trust. I do not want to do that.